# Analyzer warns that struct is uninitialized when setting one of its members

Tags: objective-c, struct, initialization, variable-assignment, static-analysis

Clang's static analyzer is giving me a warning where I am setting `mti.bounds` below. It says

> Logic Error - Passed-by-value struct argument contains uninitialized data

```
-(void)setLabelWithIndex:(int)idx signlop:(int)silop {
   int domsi= 0;
   msi= [sls objectAtIndex:idx];
   float fs= (fontFactor*mapyd)/mapH;
   if (fs< 10){  //minfont
      fs= 10;
   }else if(fs> 36){
      fs= 36;
   }
   if (signs[silop].turn){
      domsi= 1;
      [msi setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:1.25*fs]];
      msi.text= @"T";
      msi.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
      if (silop== editLastLop){
         msi.textColor= [UIColor yellowColor];
      }else{
         msi.textColor= turnMinderColor;
      }
      msi.layer.borderWidth= 0;
   }else if(signs[silop].trap){
      if (numTrapsShowing< numTrapImages){
         domsi= 0;
         numTrapsShowing++;
         lopOfTrap[numTrapsShowing-1]= silop;
         mti= [sts objectAtIndex:numTrapsShowing-1];
         CGRect butbounds;
         butbounds.size = CGSizeMake(1.25*fs, 3.5*fs);
         mti.bounds = butbounds;    // Analyzer warns here
      }else{
         domsi= -1;
      }
   }else{
```

Here's a screenshot of the analyzer output:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: A picture here is worth much less than the copy-pasted code; pictures aren't searchable. Please always put the code into your question as text; including a picture of the analyzer overlay is helpful, but shouldn't be the only thing in your post.

Comment: Thank-you for the tip, I thought the arrows were important but I can see your point, I will edit and add code.  Carmen

Comment: Great, thanks for doing that.

Comment: Again, thank you for the edits! I promise to do better next time.  Carmen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the existing bounds, modify it and set it back again:

```
CGRect bitbounds = mti.bounds;
bitbounds.size = CGSizeMake(1.25*fs, 3.5*fs);
mti.bounds = bitbounds;
```

This is because the `bounds` property uses a `CGRect` *copy*.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!!!  I was trying to change the bounds of a rotated button so I did not want to move it.  Carmen